# Applying a CAShapeLayer mask to a UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, cashapelayer

I am using this code to apply a layer to a UIview:

```
mask = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
mask.frame = baseView.layer.bounds;
CGRect biggerRect = CGRectMake(mask.frame.origin.x, mask.frame.origin.y, mask.frame.size.width, mask.frame.size.height);
CGRect smallerRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[maskPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(biggerRect), CGRectGetMinY(biggerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(biggerRect), CGRectGetMaxY(biggerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(biggerRect), CGRectGetMaxY(biggerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(biggerRect), CGRectGetMinY(biggerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(biggerRect), CGRectGetMinY(biggerRect))];

[maskPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(smallerRect), CGRectGetMinY(smallerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(smallerRect), CGRectGetMaxY(smallerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(smallerRect), CGRectGetMaxY(smallerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(smallerRect), CGRectGetMinY(smallerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(smallerRect), CGRectGetMinY(smallerRect))];

mask.path = maskPath.CGPath;
[mask setFillRule:kCAFillRuleEvenOdd];
mask.fillColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
baseView.layer.mask = mask;
```

Since the rectangle I want to cut changes, I was wonderning if there was a quick way to change the size of the mask instead of just removing it from the UIview and re-applying it with different dimensions:

e.g.

```
[mask removeFromSuperlayer];
```

and...

```
mask = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
mask.frame = baseView.layer.bounds;
CGRect biggerRect = CGRectMake(mask.frame.origin.x, mask.frame.origin.y, mask.frame.size.width, mask.frame.size.height);
CGRect smallerRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 100.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f);

UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[maskPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(biggerRect), CGRectGetMinY(biggerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(biggerRect), CGRectGetMaxY(biggerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(biggerRect), CGRectGetMaxY(biggerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(biggerRect), CGRectGetMinY(biggerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(biggerRect), CGRectGetMinY(biggerRect))];

[maskPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(smallerRect), CGRectGetMinY(smallerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(smallerRect), CGRectGetMaxY(smallerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(smallerRect), CGRectGetMaxY(smallerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(smallerRect), CGRectGetMinY(smallerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(smallerRect), CGRectGetMinY(smallerRect))];

mask.path = maskPath.CGPath;
[mask setFillRule:kCAFillRuleEvenOdd];
mask.fillColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
baseView.layer.mask = mask;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are asking whether you can reshape the mask without having to draw the path each time, unfortunately not. You can keep the mask shape the same and perform transformations on the mask by setting the [transform](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/transform) property of the `CAShapeLayer` but if you need the mask to take a different shape your going to have to draw that shape by creating a new path. **BUT** there is no need to remove the mask from the `UIView` and create an entirely new one each time you need its shape to change. Simply setting the [path](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAShapeLayer/path) property of the CAShapeLayer while it is still masking the `UIView` is sufficient for the changes to take place:

```
- (void)remask
{
    CAShapeLayer *mask = (CAShapeLayer *)self.view.layer.mask;

    CGRect biggerRect = CGRectMake(mask.frame.origin.x, mask.frame.origin.y, mask.frame.size.width, mask.frame.size.height);
    CGRect smallerRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 100.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f);

    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [maskPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(biggerRect), CGRectGetMinY(biggerRect))];
    [maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(biggerRect), CGRectGetMaxY(biggerRect))];
    [maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(biggerRect), CGRectGetMaxY(biggerRect))];
    [maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(biggerRect), CGRectGetMinY(biggerRect))];
    [maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(biggerRect), CGRectGetMinY(biggerRect))];

    [maskPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(smallerRect), CGRectGetMinY(smallerRect))];
    [maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(smallerRect), CGRectGetMaxY(smallerRect))];
    [maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(smallerRect), CGRectGetMaxY(smallerRect))];
    [maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(smallerRect), CGRectGetMinY(smallerRect))];
    [maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(smallerRect), CGRectGetMinY(smallerRect))];

    mask.path = maskPath.CGPath;
}
```

On a side note, are you aware that instead of drawing each rectangle manually you could create the mask path using the following code:

```
mask = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
mask.frame = baseView.layer.bounds;
CGRect biggerRect = CGRectMake(mask.frame.origin.x, mask.frame.origin.y, mask.frame.size.width, mask.frame.size.height);
CGRect smallerRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 100.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f);

CGMutablePathRef maskPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddRect(maskPath, NULL, biggerRect);
CGPathAddRect(maskPath, NULL, smallerRect);

mask.path = maskPath;
[mask setFillRule:kCAFillRuleEvenOdd];
mask.fillColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
baseView.layer.mask = mask;

CGPathRelease(maskPath);
```

I thought I'd just point it out as it may be of convenience to you in the future.

Comment: Seems great, but whats the difference?

Comment: @Alessandro Well the result is identical but other than that: less lines of code + arguably more readable/obvious + uses lightweight C API instead of 'heavyweight' `UIBezierPath` object so it's probably a tiny bit more performant. Just pointing out the 'AddRect' functions for convenience in the future. In reality I just needed something to accompany the bad news of my answer that want you'd like to do isn't directly possible haha.